# How to delete all minimum values from array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a array of `[2 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 6]`, and want to delete all minimum values from it.

The output should be `[3 4 4 5 6 6 6]`.

I tried like following code, but it deleted a single `2`, and left `[2 3 4 4 5 6 6 6]`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6])
b= np.delete(a, a.argmin())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)
- [Numpy: Indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
- [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) or not to [`a.min()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) depends on the array size.

  - For small arrays, use python built-in min
  - For large arrays, use numpy min
- Test the timing for your particular usage.

```py
b = a[a > min(a)]

[b]:
array([3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in function for finding `min`

```
val = min(values)
b =[v for v in values if v != val]
```

Comment: It works fine. Try to find a native numpy function to avoid looping whenever possible, so you take advantage of numpy's C implementation for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The size of numpy arrays is immutable but you can create a copy of this array using this simple oneliner:

```
arr = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6])
arr[arr!=np.min(arr)]
```

#### Output:

```
array([3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices that are greater than minimum value and slice the array as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672267/6692898).

```
out = a[a>a.min()]
```

Notice this is faster than using `np.delete` as explained in the linked answer.